# Did Kim Jong-un order the partial evacuation of Pyongyang in North Korea?

Tags: war, north-korea

[Pravda.ru reported](http://www.pravdareport.com/hotspots/conflicts/12-04-2017/137480-pyongyang_evacuation-0/) on April 12, 2017 that Pyongyang was being partially evacuated in fear of large-scale war with the USA:

> North Koreaт (sic) leader Kim Jong-un ordered 25 percent of Pyongyang residents to leave the city immediately.
>
> In accordance with the order, 600,000 people should be urgently evacuated. Experts note that the evacuation will most likely be conducted due to extremely strained tensions in relations with the United States of America.

I have searched other news sites - no one except for the [UK's Express](http://www.express.co.uk/news/world/791251/kim-jong-un-north-korea-imminent-war-pyongyang-immediate-evacuation) are covering this story.

Is it true?

Comment: Thanks to @Oddthinking for the edit.  Though an SE user I was unsure as to the format I should use here.  Lesson learned and I hope to write better questions in future.  Thanks once again!

Comment: This question was closed in 2017 because it was about an on-going event, but maybe it deserves to be reopened now ?